# The answer to the equation $\log_3x+\log_2x+\log_4x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The answer to the equation :

$$\log_3x+\log_2x+\log_4x=1$$

---

my try :

$$\log_3x+\log_2x+\log_4x=1\\ \log_2x+\log_2\sqrt{x}+\log_{3}x=1\\\log_2x\sqrt{x}=\log_{3}{\dfrac{3}{x}}$$

now ?

Comment: An interesting formulation: $x^3=\exp(H(\ln 2, \ln 3, \ln 4))$, where $H$ is harmonic mean of it's arguments.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: That's incorrect. Try $n=1$ or $n=0$ or $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$\log_2x+\log_3x+\log_4x=1$

$\frac{\log x}{\log 2}+\frac{\log x}{\log 3} + \frac{\log x}{\log 4}=1$

$\log x \left(\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{1}{\log 3} + \frac{1}{\log 4}\right)=1$

$\log x=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{1}{\log 3} + \frac{1}{\log 4}}$

$x = e^{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{1}{\log 3} + \frac{1}{\log 4}}}$

$x = 1.384417...$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\log_2 x +\log_3 x +\log_4 x =1 \\
\frac{ \ln x}{ \ln2}+\frac{ \ln x}{ \ln3}+\frac{ \ln x}{ \ln4}=1 \\
\ln x = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\ln 2}+\frac{1}{\ln 3}+\frac{1}{\ln 4}}
\end{eqnarray*}
which gives $ \ln x=0.32579 \cdots$ and  $x=\color{red}{1.384 \cdots} $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Remember the change base property of log: You can choose any term, say $\log_2 x$, and then write the other two terms of the left side of the equation in term of $\log_2 x$ as follows: $\log_3 x = \log_3 2\cdot \log_2 x, \log_4 x = \log_4 2\cdot \log_2 x$, and factor out $\log_2 x$ on the left side.